# async function in useEffect, react

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I have a problem.

there is a need to perform two asynchronous requests. The second is executed with the results of the first. For some reason the data is not being rendered. If I execute only the first request, then the data is rendered. If I add the second, then the data is not displayed.

```
export const getMatches = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`https://***/matches`);
    const filteredLive = data.filter((item: TMatches) => item.live);
    console.log(filteredLive, 'filteredLive');
    return filteredLive;
}

    export const getMatchesWithStats = async (matches: TMatches[]) => {
                const matchesWithStats: TMatches[] = [];
            
                matches.map(async (match) => {
                        const { data } = await axios.get(`***/match?id=${match.id}`);
                        match.match = data;
                        matchesWithStats.push(match);
                });
            
                return matchesWithStats;
            }
        
        export const Matches = () => {
        
            const [matches, setMatches] = useState<TMatches[]>([]);
            const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
      
            useEffect(() => {
              
                  const getUseMatch = async () => {
                      const dataMatches = await getMatches();
                      const dataMatchesWithStats = await getMatchesWithStats(dataMatches);
                      setMatches(dataMatchesWithStats);
                  }
                  getUseMatch();
            }, []);
        
            const matchesRendered = matches.map((match) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <StyledTeamName variant="h6">
                    <StyledIconLive>
                      <img src="/live.png" width="32" />
                    </StyledIconLive>
                    &nbsp;
                    {match.team1.name} - {match.team2.name}
                  </StyledTeamName>
                  <StyledTeamNameSubTitle>{match.event.name}</StyledTeamNameSubTitle>
                </>
              );
            });
        
            return <>{isLoading && matchesRendered}</>;
        }
```

can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMatchesWithStats` internally has an `async` operation which is never `await`ed, so it will always return an empty array.

The callback to `.map` is `async`:

```
matches.map(async (match) => {
```

That callback *internally* awaits its own asynchronous operations, but nothing ever awaits the Promises *returned* by `map()`.  You can do that with `Promise.all`.  For example:

```
await Promise.all(matches.map(async (match) => {
  //...
}));

return matchesWithStats;
```

Answer (score 0):

The promises created within the map method callback are not being awaited so the array is returned and the state is set before it has any elements. Modifying arrays asynchronously is error-prone so create an array instead like this:

```
export const getMatchesWithStats = (matches: TMatches[]) => {
  const matchesWithStats = matches.map(async (match) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`***/match?id=${match.id}`);
    return { ...match, match: data };
  });

  return Promise.all(matchesWithStats);
}
```